# In the proof of Proposition 16.33 of John Lee's smooth manifold (Geometric Interpretation of the Divergence)

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading John Lee's Introduction to Smooth manifold, Second Edition, Proof of the Proposition 16.33 and some question arises :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true? Why such regular coordinate ball $B$ and sufficiently small $t>0$ exists?

First note that $\operatorname{div}(X|_U) = (\operatorname{div}X)|_U > 0 $ (We maybe show this). So by the first part of the proof, $X|_U$ generates a volume-decreasing flow $\eta$ on $U$. It means that for every compact regular domain $D$, $\operatorname{vol}(\eta_{t}(D))$ is strictly decreasing as a function of $t$ whenever the domain of $\eta_t$ contains $D$. And I don't know how to connect this fact to our desired statement, involving $\theta$. What relation between $\eta$ and $\theta$ can we use? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\text{div}(X):M\to\Bbb{R}$ is a smooth function, and so it is continuous. If there is a point $p\in M$ where $\text{div}(X)(p)<0$, then by continuity there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $\text{div}(X)|_U<0$. This is a basic fact about continuous functions. Next, coordinate balls $B$ with closure in $U$ always exist for obvious reasons. The set $U$ is open in the manifold $M$, so you can consider any chart $(V,\psi)$ such that $p\in V$. Then, $(V\cap U,\psi|_{V\cap U})$ is another chart for $M$ (belonging to the maximal atlas) and this chart has domain contained in $U$. Now, you look at $\psi(V\cap U)$; this is an open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ around $\psi(p)$. So, by definition of how the topology on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is given, there exists a ball $B'$ centred at $p$ and having closure in $\psi(V\cap U)$. So, $B=\psi^{-1}(B')$ is the desired coordinate ball. There's actually no need to restrict to coordinate balls here. The argument follows through verbatim if you consider any compact subset $K\subset U$ (assuming of course you know how to deal with integrals over arbitrary compact sets... basic Riemann integrals have a little bit of trouble with this, so in that case, you'll want to assume $K$ has a nice enough boundary, but if you know Lebesgue, then there's no reason to be worried at all).

Next, $B$ has compact closure, so the properties of flows tell us there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\overline{B}\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is inside the domain of the flow map $\theta$ (because the domain of flow maps is an open set in $M\times\Bbb{R}$ which contains $M\times \{0\}$, so if you restrict to a compact part of the manifold, you can find a single $\epsilon$ which "works"). So for any $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, $\theta_t(\overline{B})$ is well-defined, and if you make $\epsilon$ even smaller, you can ensure that this set again lies inside $U$. This is what's meant by "for $t$ small enough".

Also, why do you introduce a new letter $\eta$? The letter $\theta$ already denotes the flow of the vector field $X$.

---

*Edit:*

I realized in my second paragraph  "and if you make $\epsilon$ even smaller..." pretty much translates to "it exists because it obviously exists", so as written it may not be that helpful. Here's what I mean.

By definition, the flow, $\theta$, of a smooth vector field, $X$, on $M$ is a (necessarily smooth, due to classical theorems about ODEs in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and hence continuous) map $\theta:\Omega\to M$, where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $M\times \Bbb{R}$ containing $M\times \{0\}$ (this is a consequence of ODE theory). Here's the claim we're making:

> For any open set $U\subset M$, and any compact set $K\subset U$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, the set $\theta_t(K)$ is defined an contained in $U$.

This is actually a purely topological result. First, $\theta:\Omega\to M$ is a continuous map, so openness of $U\subset M$ implies $\theta^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $\Omega$, and hence of $M\times \Bbb{R}$. So, for each $x\in K$, the point $(x,0)$ lies in $K\times \{0\}\subset U\times \{0\}\subset \theta^{-1}(U)$, so there is (by definition of the product topology on $M\times \Bbb{R}$) an open set $V_x\subset M$ and an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $V_x\times (-\epsilon_x,\epsilon_x)\subset \theta^{-1}(U)$. Hence, $\{V_x\times (-\epsilon_x,\epsilon_x)\}_{x\in K}$ is an open cover of $K\times \{0\}$ (which is a compact set, because it is a product of compact sets). So, by compactness, it has a finite subcover, say $\{V_{x_i}\times (-\epsilon_{x_i},\epsilon_{x_i})\}_{i=1}^N$. Now, define $\epsilon=\min(\epsilon_{x_1},\dots, \epsilon_{x_N})$ (minimum of finitely many positive numbers exists and is positive... this is where compactness is crucial). Then, we have
\begin{align}
K\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^NV_{x_i}\times (-\epsilon_{x_i},\epsilon_{x_i})\subset \theta^{-1}(U)\subset \Omega.
\end{align}
The fact that $K\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is contained in $\Omega$ (final inclusion) tells us for each $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, the set $\theta_t(K)$ is well-defined. The fact that $K\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset \theta^{-1}(U)$ (second last inclusion) tells us $\theta_t(K)$ is contained in $U$, and this is precisely what we want.

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation. Can I ask a question? Why such $V_x \subset M$ and $\epsilon_x >0$ exists for each $x \in K$? And why $\{ V_x \times (-\epsilon_x , \epsilon_x) \}_{x\in K}$ is an open cover of $K \times \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: @Plantation now you need to look at the definitions of "open" for your first question and "open cover" for your second question. Think about it for a while (trust me, it's easier for you to think about it rather than me explain). If this is not clear, it means you need to review some basic topology definitions.

Comment: If $ K \times \{0 \} \subseteq \theta^{-1}(U)$ , then it seems possible. If $K \subset U$, this condition is satisfied, since $\theta(p,0) = p$. For the coordinate ball $B$ you suggest above, since $\bar{B} \subseteq U$, we may not worry about..

Comment: @Plantation oh yes, I should have said $K\subset U$, not $M$. There's a few such typos, which I'll fix now.

Comment: Yes. Can I ask furthur? How can we deduce $\operatorname{vol}(\theta_t(\bar{B})) < \operatorname{vol}(\bar{B})$? One of reason that I introduce the new letter $\eta$ is, possibility of difference between the flow $\theta$ generated from $X$ and the flow $\eta$ generated from the restricted vector field $X|_U$. We know that "$\operatorname{vol}(\eta_t(D))$  is strictly decreasing as a function of $t$ whenever the domain of $\eta_t$ contains $D$, where $D$ is compact regular domain of $U$. But  how can we prove the desired strict inequality..

Comment: @Plantation first, there shouldn't be a need to introduce the restriction of the vector field. And second, you should be able to verify that $\eta$ is the restriction of $\theta$ (flow of restriction is restriction of flow... one way to argue is by uniqueness of solutions to ODEs, and the fact that ODE's, and more generally, differentiation itself are local in nature). Since you have a strictly decreasing function, for $t>0$, $\text{vol}(\theta_t(D))<\text{vol}(\theta_0(D))=\text{vol}(D)$.

Comment: Yes. I'll try it. Thank you very much~~